# creating physical file

Tags: c#, wpf

As was learning how to deal with visual object on WPF I ran into a snippet on MSDN as following. It runs but not sure how I can serialize it. Question is how I can create a file (*.bmp) physically here?

[URL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingvisual.aspx)

Thanks!

```
Image myImage = new Image();
FormattedText text = new FormattedText("ABC",
        new CultureInfo("en-us"),
        FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
        new Typeface(this.FontFamily, FontStyles.Normal, FontWeights.Normal, new FontStretch()),
        this.FontSize,
        this.Foreground);

DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen();
drawingContext.DrawText(text, new Point(2, 2));
drawingContext.Close();

RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap(180, 180, 120, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
bmp.Render(drawingVisual);
myImage.Source = bmp;
```

After adding Save() method:

```
    Image myImage = new Image();
    FormattedText text = new FormattedText("ABC",
        new CultureInfo("en-us"),
        FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
        new Typeface(this.FontFamily, FontStyles.Normal, FontWeights.Normal, 
        new FontStretch()),
        this.FontSize,
        this.Foreground);
    DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
    DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen();
    drawingContext.Close();

    RenderTargetBitmap bmp = 
         new RenderTargetBitmap(180, 180, 120, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
    bmp.Render(drawingVisual);
    myImage.Source = bmp;

    var enc = new PngBitmapEncoder();
    enc.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmp));
    using (var fs = new FileStream("c:\\temp\\Test.png", 
                   FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        enc.Save(fs);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`BitmapEncoder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapencoder.aspx) ([`BmpBitmapEncoder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bmpbitmapencoder.aspx) for *.bmp files, but I suggest you [`PngBitmapEncoder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.pngbitmapencoder.aspx) since your image has transparency and will be converted to a completely black .bmp):

```
var enc = new PngBitmapEncoder();
enc.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmp));
using(var fs = new FileStream("Test.png", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    enc.Save(fs);
}
```

Comment: @@Max Thanks although it goes all the way and generates a PNG file, however, it is empty. I mean there is no ABC on it.  any idea?

Comment: No idea, your code + my snippet produced a valid .png file with 'ABC' on transparent background for me.

Comment: You've somehow lost `drawingContext.DrawText(text, new Point(2, 2));
` call before `drawingContext.Close();`.